# Pandas - replace values of a column if other values from same row appear in second data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Input are two dataframes. Below are short versions of them with only a few rows.

```
df1
+-----+------+------+
| No  | Type | Desc |
+-----+------+------+
| 123 | A    | Bla  |
| 123 | B    | Bla  |
| 123 | D    | Bla  |
| 342 | A    | Bla  |
| 342 | C    | Bla  |
| 543 | B    | Bla  |
| 543 | C    | Bla  |
+-----+------+------+

df2
+-----+------+------+
| No  | Type | Desc |
+-----+------+------+
| 123 | A    | Lala |
| 342 | A    | Lala |
| 342 | C    | Lala |
+-----+------+------+
```

Both data frames have more than the columns above, but the others do not matter in this case.

I would like to change values of column `Desc` to `Done` for rows of `df1` in case this row (meaning `No` and `Type`) also appear in `df2`.

```
df1
+-----+------+------+
| No  | Type | Desc |
+-----+------+------+
| 123 | A    | Done |
| 123 | B    | Bla  |
| 123 | D    | Bla  |
| 342 | A    | Done |
| 342 | C    | Done |
| 543 | B    | Bla  |
| 543 | C    | Bla  |
+-----+------+------+
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df3 = df1[['No','Type']].merge(df2, on=['No','Type'], how='left')
df3['Desc'] = np.where(df3['Desc'].notnull(), 'Done', df1['Desc'])
print (df3)
    No Type  Desc
0  123    A  Done
1  123    B   Bla
2  123    D   Bla
3  342    A  Done
4  342    C  Done
5  543    B   Bla
6  543    C   Bla
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What can I do if I want to keep the other columns of df1? As I mentioned, there are more columns (about 10) and they should stay as they are in df1. With this solution, They are all `NaN` in the output df.

Comment: @MaMo - Then is possible use `df1.merge(df2, on=['No','Type'], how='left')`, but get suffixes for same columns in both dfs

Comment: It worked but I also had to change the second row to `df3['Desc_x'] = np.where(df3['Desc_y'].notnull(), 'Done', df3['Desc_x'])` because column Desc appears in both data frames and is no merge-criteria. Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the rows of `df1`, that are present in `df2` with a left merge and then change the `Desc` to `Done`.

```
mer = df1.merge(df2, on=['No', 'Type'], how='left')
mer.loc[mer['Desc_y'].notnull(), 'Desc_x'] = 'Done'
df1['Desc'] = mer['Desc_x']
```

Output:

```
    No  Type Desc
0   123 A   Done
1   123 B   Bla
2   123 D   Bla
3   342 A   Done
4   342 C   Done
5   543 B   Bla
6   543 C   Bla
```